# Помогите, пожалуйста, найти книги для курсовой

Tags: языкознание

Я пишу работу (бакалавр) о ложных друзьях переводчика и ищу книги, тексты, которые могут мне помочь. Убедительно прошу вас о помощи, поскольку на польском языке мало книг на эту тему. Мой e-mail - klaudia.celeban@gmail.com. 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите тут: http://my-shop.ru/
По идее, должно быть. Я там много чего нашла в свое время для своей курсовой :)